# Не получается добавить библиотеку

Tags: c#

В References солюшн не могу добавить библиотеку ModelDefaultAttribute, а она очень нужна. Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: а что вы делали, чтобы ее добавить?

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека должна называться примерно так:

DevExpress.ExpressApp.v12.2.dll

Отличаться может версия. Именно её и надо добавить в References...

Answer (score 1):

Указанный атрибут находится в библиотеке DevExpress.ExpressApp.vxx.x.dll ([Ссылка на документацию](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xaf/clsDevExpressExpressAppModelModelDefaultAttributetopic))